# Extract information from html page using css selector

Tags: html, css, select

I want to select some information such as "Room1", "Room2", "Room3" from html page (see below) using css selector and print it "How can do that?" :

```
                <div class="bloco-imovel-resumo-dados">
                    <div id="Cpl_modulodadosresumidos_module_holder" class="modulo-dados-resumidos">

<h2 class="lbl_descricao_dados"> My Information</h2>

<ul class="bloco-dados">

    <li>
        <b>Room1:</b> <span>Renewed</span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Room2:</b><span> 30 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Room3:</b><span> 2 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Room4:</b><span> 4 </span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Room 5:</b><span> 5 </span></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: With what language? And what have you tried?

Comment: CSS alone can't do that ... with e.g. javascript, have a look at `document.querySelector('ul.bloco-dados li b').textContent` or `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: I am a beginner in css so could you please help me in some steps how can i do that?

Comment: There is no special language I should. I just want to make a selection of some information in HTML. I made some search, but because I am a beginner of using css selctor and I don't have an experience so I need really to your help.

Comment: I tried to use "querySelectorAll()" to extract some information from listing.html page as following: Selector_1 = listing.querySelectorAll("Room1");

Comment: and I have recived this error:NameError: name 'listing' is not defined. Do you know how I can FIX this error

Comment: @Elwakdy Do you need to get a list of `Room1`, `Room2`, `Room3`, ... etc? or do you need get the text inside `<span>` tag by specifying `Room1` or `Room2` or `Room3` ... etc?

Comment: I want to get the inside <span> tag by specifying Room1 or Room2 or Room3 by following this structure:

Selector1 = "WRITE SELECTOR HERE (Room1)"
Selector2 = "WRITE SELECTOR HERE (Room2)"

and then print them following this format:

print('Room1: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_1)[0].text))
print('')

where "tree" got from this code:

from lxml import html,etree

with open(r'listing.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)

Comment: I want to make Data Extraction from html page using CSS and REGEX

Comment: @Elwakdy Sorry, I didn't understand your explanation perfectly, Please look at my answer, It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
Nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".bloco-dados li")
Data = [] // new array
for (I = 0; I < Nodes.length; I++) {
    DataName = Nodes[I].firstChild.innerText // <b> tag is the first child node of <li> tag
    DataName = DataName.substr(0, DataName.length - 1) // Remove last character (the colon)
    DataValue = Nodes[I].lastChild.innerText // <span> tag is the last child node of <li> tag
    Data[DataName] = DataValue
}
alert(Data["Room 1"])
alert(Data["Room 2"])
alert(Data["Room 3"])
alert(Data["Room 4"])
alert(Data["Room 5"])
```